# SignalR custom client does not work with the properties

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to use an custom client with properties, but I get an exception with a message like "client type must not contain properties". Why so? Everything works without properties.

```
public interface IClient 
{
    string Vote { get; set; } //does not work with properties
    Task ReceiveMessage(string method, string user, string message);
}
```

```
public class ChatHub : Hub<IClient>
{
   public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
   {
       await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage("ReceiveMessage", user, message); //here I can't send messages because of the "Voice" property of the interface "IClient"
   }
}
```

Comment: If you can not use properties, you can create a `IClient` without properties and a wrapper for it with properties and reference to `IClient` instance

Comment: @GoodboY it also doesn't work

Comment: Hi @taubomn, as far as I known, signalr does not support with properties. Besides, you said if you remove property it also does not work. Could you pls share more code with us and what's the error message?

Comment: @Rena everything works without properties. If I do as a GoodboY
offers, then in class I will need to implement the method of sending, I can not do it because, I do not know the code of ReceiveMessage (SendMessage). No extra code, the error I'm getting is "Type must not contain properties." and that's all. If you say that SignalR does not support properties, what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to split my properties to a separate interface, and then inherit from both in my concrete client class. This has an additional benefit that you can then use the properties with Dependency Injection, and they will come from your implementation.

```cs
public interface IClient 
{
    Task ReceiveMessage(string method, string user, string message);
}

public interface IClientProperties
{
    string Vote { get; set; }
}

public class ChatClient : IClient, IClientProperties
{
    public string Vote { get; set; }
    public Task ReceiveMessage(string method, string user, string message)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class ChatHub : Hub<IClient>
{
   public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
   {
       await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage("ReceiveMessage", user, message); 
   }
}
```